# Django How to get a one variable from a user's list?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have something like this:

```
 a = User.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
```

how can I get a one variable from user's list?

I tried a[0] but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#first) method:

```
a = User.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id').first()
```

BTW, `a[0]` should work too.  Are you sure that `User` table contains any records?  If this table is empty then `first()` will return `None`.